# Integrate Xcode with Boost Unit Test framework

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, boost

is there any painless way to integrate *Xcode* **(>=8.*)** with Boost unit test framework? I wounder if it is worth it.

Comment: Define "painless".

Comment: I mean, if I can do it in 30 minutes and focus on my project.

Comment: Still subjective, what one person can do in 5 minutes might take others days. There are plenty of instructions available if you take some time to google it (I just did and there is quite a bit on the first page).